# Ternary operator with Linq-to-SQL causing problems?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq-to-SQL statement:

```
return db.Photos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PhotoID == id
                                              && includePending ? true : p.Live);
```

For includePending I am passing false. In the database, "Live" is true for all but 2 photos.

However instead of returning one photo as expected, it returns ALL photos in the database except for 2! PhotoID is a primary key (thus can only be true for one item) and boolean logic states that FALSE AND TRUE = FALSE. So what's going on here? Why is it ignoring the `p.PhotoID == id` portion of my query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't remember the [full precedence rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) by heart, but your condition is equivalent to:

```
p => (p.PhotoID == id && includePending) ? true : p.Live
```

whereas you want:

```
p => p.PhotoID == id && (includePending ? true : p.Live)
```

Just use the latter form to make it explicit, or even change it to not use the conditional:

```
p => p.PhotoID == id && (includePending || p.Live)
```

which I'd argue is simpler. I would suggest that in situations like this you use bracketing to make the logic clearer even when the precedence rules work in your favour.

You could even use two where clauses:

```
.Where(p => p.PhotoID == id)
.Where(p => includePending || p.live)
```

or even conditionalise the second:

```
var query = ...
               .Where(p => p.PhotoID == id);

if (!includePending)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.live);
}
```

Comment: +1. just including this precedence list for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: @Mitch: Yup. I still wouldn't bother learning it by rote though, for relatively rare things like this - I'd rather make it explicit *either* way.

Comment: Haha! I can't even think of a decent excuse to make. Guess that's what happens when you work into the early hours of the morning. ;) Thanks for your answer.